# How to update the page & simultaneously load the updated data in angular 6?

Tags: angular

So this is the code which Im using to call a popup. In the popup I have two buttons like yes & No. So after clicking Yes, I would call a function APIupdate(). It updates my backend via ajax call. Now I need to get the updated values in the html page, simultaneously after updating the values.

My point is after updating the value in the pop up, I need to display the updated value in the html page where Im calling the popup.

TS 1:

```
  openmodal(key: any): void {
    let obj = this.modal.show(CompleteComponent, undefined, {
        Key: Key
    }).subscribe((r) => {
        if (r.click === 'COMPLETE') {
            this.APIToken();  // calling api
            obj.unsubscribe();
        }
    });
}
```

Popup TS 2:

```
  APIupdate(statusText, reqid): void {
   this._call.update(statusText,reqid)  //ajax call
  .subscribe(r => {
    this.details = r;
    this.evt.emit({
      'click': 'COMPLETE'
    });
    this.modal.hide(); //pop up hide
  });
 }
```

So I tried using emit event, but that doesnt update my html page simultaneously. I need to refresh the page to see the changes. Can somebody give me a solution to this please?

Answer (score 0):

In your example you could use `detectChanges` of the [ChangeDectectorRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef) service. What it does is triggering the change detection of Angular manually, which will re-render your templates if needed.

```
export class ComponentA {
    constructor(private cd: ChangeDectectorRef) {}

    update(): void {
        this.call.update().subscribe(() => {
            // things you need to do
            this.cd.detectChanges();
        })
    }
}
```

However, I recommend to avoid calling the change detection yourself. The moment you need to call it you should question your architecture.

Definitely take a look at the [async pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe).

Answer (score 0):

Post that data to the parent, as far as I understood your code:

```
this.evt.emit({
  'click': 'COMPLETE', data: r
});
```

and handle it in subscriber of `this.modal.show`

Comment: Thank you so much. Can you please tell me how to handle it ?

Comment: Well it depends on how you displaying that data. :)
Assign it to class variable iside `if (r.click === 'COMPLETE') {` something like `this.myDataFromPopup = r.data;` and use it in template `<div>{{myDataFromPopup | json }}</div>`